# Dualboot : Install Win10 alongside Debian, not the opposite

Tags: debian, windows, grub

I have Linux Debian installed on my laptop for some years (HDD0, sda).
I just added a 2nd hard drive that holds Win10 (HDD1, sdb)

I would like to setup a dualboot with these 2 OS.

I found tons of tutos to implement dualboots but they seem to apply when Windows is installed first then linux in a second step; and I'm not a GRUB specialist...

I can access Win10 hard drive and browse within the file system from Linux.

I tried sudo grub-install -> no sucess

I tried os-prober -> return is empty

If I change the boot options in the BIOS, in order to boot Win10/HDD1 first, instead of Debian/HDD0, it does not work : Win10 is skiped and  Debian is launched.
I guess win10 is not well recognized as a bootable OS...

Can any body help me to fix this issue and setup the dualboot ?

Thanks
Cez

Answer (score 1):

Setting boot is difficult. There is no "one size fits all" solution.

You might be lucky and find that your linux distribution could detect all the OS installed and then, it is as simple as asking grub to build the correct config file to boot. There are many guides to install Linux **after** Windows, because Windows doesn't play nice with any other OS. Windows installation usually ends on it taking ownership of the boot sector or setting itself as the (only) boot OS. That could be corrected with Linux, yes, and there are many guides to that effect.

As Ubuntu is a modified Debian, maybe [this would help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows).

Or, from [an Archlinux point of view](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=244300).

## Why?

The complexity comes from the fact that there are **many** different BIOS firmware (each might have different options to boot), then, you need to know if the boot needs to be directly from BIOS or from GPT. An added twist is that one of your disks might use one the other disk might use the other. And then, each OS might have some specific changes that are *obvious* to their **experienced** users. Obviously not for a new user.

If the above doesn't help, the next level in *simple* boot setting is to [use a **boot-loader**](https://www.ubuntupit.com/best-linux-bootloader-for-home-and-embedded-systems/) (yes, `grub` is actually a boot-loader, but needs to configured from inside a running Linus OS) or a **Live test** OS (probably the [Ubuntu Live](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started) for ease of use). Yes, Debian has some [live versions](https://www.debian.org/CD/live/), but not with a `testing` version that is easy to boot.

Please try some options and ask if in doubt.